# InterruptedException wasn't thrown when the thread was interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading

I created two classes, `CheckTimer` is used to interrupt `thread1` when 0.3 seconds is passed. I noticed that `thread.interrupted()` was executed in `CheckTimer.run()`, but `InterruptedException` in the main function wasn't thrown, `thread1` continued running without any hint of stopping, why? Isn't `thread1.interrupted()` supposed to stop `thread1`?

```
class CheckTimer extends Thread
{

    /** indicate whether the thread should be running */
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    /** Thread that may be interrupted */
    private Thread thread;

    private int duration;
    private int length;

    public CheckTimer(int length, Thread thread)
    {
        this.duration = 0;
        this.thread = thread;
        this.length = length;
    }


    /** Performs timer specific code */
    public void run()
    {
        // Keep looping
        while(running)
        {
            // Put the timer to sleep
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ioe)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Use 'synchronized' to prevent conflicts
            synchronized ( this )
            {
                // Increment time remaining
                duration += 100;

                // Check to see if the time has been exceeded
                if (duration > length)
                {
                    // Trigger a timeout
                    thread.interrupt();
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Thread1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("thread1 is running...");
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread1();
        CheckTimer timer = new CheckTimer(300, thread1);

        timer.start();
        thread1.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no call to `thread1.interrupt()` anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's now how it is supposed to work.

You have to check if `Thread1` is being interrupted and then throw the exception yourself.

The exception is used in the `Thread.sleep()` for example, and how it is implemented is like the code below.

Example:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

More information on it: [Interrupted Exception Article](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/20/interrupted-exception.html)